# How many attacks does a cleric have?

Tags: dnd-5e, cleric

I kept looking through my Player's Handbook and online to see if I could find it, but no luck. I'm pretty sure it's only one, but I need some confirmation.

How many attacks does a cleric have?

Comment: What Domain is this Cleric and level? Are we talking about _Extra Attack_ (the feature) or do bonus action attacks count? Does the Cleric gave feats or other items?

Comment: Basically, what makes you think you have more than one? Can you put in the question the text you read?

Answer (score 3):

### Only War Clerics receive the ability to make two weapon attacks in one turn with one weapon.

Clerics are one of the few classes that do not receive extra weapon attacks when taking the Attack option, or *Extra Attack*.

However, the War Domain Cleric receives a special feature for its martial prowess.

> **War Priest** (PHB Pg. 63)
>
> From 1st level, your god delivers bolts of
> inspiration to you while you are engaged in battle. When you use the
> Attack action, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action. You
> can use this feature a number of times equal to your Wisdom modifier
> (a minimum of once). You regain all expended uses when you finish a
> long rest.

Most other clerics, however, including War Cleric, supplement extra elemental damage in the place where a multiattack would usually take place.

> **Divine Strike** (PHB Pg. 63)
>
> At 8th level, you gain the ability to infuse your weapon strikes with
> divine energy. Once on each of your turns when you hit a creature
> with a weapon attack, you can cause the attack to deal an extra 1d8
> damage of the same type dealt by the weapon to the target. When you
> reach 14th level, the extra damage increases to 2d8.

However, Knowledge and Light Domain Clerics recieve Potent Spellcasting instead of this, so watch out for that if you're looking specifically for multiple attacks.

> **Potent Spellcasting**
>
> Starting at 8th level, you add your Wisdom modifier to the damage you deal with any cleric cantrip.

Answer (score 0):

Clerics have 1 attack with the Attack action at all levels. Like everyone else they can use two-weapon fighting with their bonus action if they use light melee weapons. A war domain cleric can use their bonus action to make a weapon attack when they take the Attack action.

Answer (score -2):

A war priest can at 1st level use their bonus action to give their same weapon a second attack a number of times per long rest equal to their wisdom bonus.

Any cleric can make **two attacks per round like all characters**, using their basic attack, and then **an offhand weapon** with their *bonus action*, as long as you follow the rules for two weapon fighting, on page 195 of the player's handbook, which reads:

> **Two-Weapon Fighting** When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use
>   a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that
>   you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier
>   to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.
>   If either weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon,
>   instead of making a melee attack with it.

So if you didn't have an ability modifier to begin with, you would appear to have two consistent attacks. Light Melee weapons that clerics can use include:
All Simple Weapons, plus Domain Proficiencies.

The Domains Tempest and War Include Martial Weapons as bonus Proficiencies.

The Weapons that are light and simple include:
club, dagger, handaxe, light hammer, sickle

The weapons that are light and martial include:
scimitar and shortsword

These weapons all deal either 1d4 or 1d6 damage. The two key differences with the War Priest using their bonus attack on the same weapon, is that it could be a considerably bigger weapon, such as a maul (2d6) or great axe (d12), *and* your damage bonus from strength (ability bonus in general for finesse weapons) applies to both attacks. This makes the War Priest's two attacks better than everybody else's two attacks. Special feats, options and true extra attacks are provided to classes like fighters, paladins, bards, barbarians, and rangers, that can partially or wholly mitigate the off hand penalties OR imitate/surpass on a permanent basis the War Priest's extra attack with a full sized weapon.

But the Cleric ultimately has the same number of attacks as every class that doesn't have extras, because they use their "bonus action" normally used for things like two weapon fighting for their second attack. Even wizards technically have 2 attacks per round when dual wielding, in the strictest sense, because of the 5th edition action economy.